# Test to use for ordinal dependent variable

Tags: ordinal-data, fishers-exact-test

We collected samples of bacteria from several locations, and looked for growth of colonies with resistance to 3 different antibiotics. An example of the data might look like (where denominators are the number of colonies from that location, pooling over multiple Petri dishes).
[image]

How do we test for the effect of location on incidence of multiple resistance? Is this a case for Chi square? Fisher's Exact Test? However, the data are not quite nominal... the probability that a colony had dual resistance will be dependent on the probability that it had single resistance, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that a count regression model would be the best way to go here, at least as a first attempt. If the table is a relatively accurate version of what you have, then maybe a zero inflated negative binomial regression.

Comment: Thanks!  We expect to have many more samples over time, but zeroes will be common.